# Office 2013 Apps publishing not listed in apps from "Shared Folder"

Tags: ms-office, office-2013

I am trying to create an Office 2013 app by publishing on Network Share. For this I created the following Manifest file,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ver="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0"
xsi:type="ContentApp">
  <Id>df5b5660-84ce-11e1-b0c4-0800200c9a66</Id>
  <AlternateId>en-US\WA123456789</AlternateId>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Sample content app" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Describe the features of this app." />

  <Hosts>
     <Host Name="Presentation" />
     <Host Name="Excel" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.bing.com" />
    <RequestedWidth>400</RequestedWidth> 
    <RequestedHeight>400</RequestedHeight>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <AllowSnapshot>true</AllowSnapshot>
</OfficeApp>
```

And after that I added the entry in Trusted Apps catalog,

[image: TrustedCatalogSettings]

But I am not able to see my app in the list here,

[image: AppsListing]

Please guide me whats wrong am doing here.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Microsoft have released a service pack which needs updated version of the manifest, Below is the working manifest...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:type="ContentApp">
  <Id>01eac144-e55a-45a7-b6e3-f1cc60ab0126</Id>
  <AlternateId>en-US\WA123456789</AlternateId>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Sample content app" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Describe the features of this app." />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/ENUSIcon.png" />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
    <Host Name="Presentation" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.bing.com" />
    <RequestedWidth>400</RequestedWidth> 
    <RequestedHeight>400</RequestedHeight>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <AllowSnapshot>true</AllowSnapshot>
</OfficeApp>
```